# Realtime game server for 10000 players

Tags: mysql, jboss, server, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have an application server (Wildfly) connected to a Database (MySQL) that needs to handle requests from 10000 players simultaneously.

Clients send their positions to the server using a call like : https://mytestserver.utd/update?x=7&y=8

In order to handle that quickly and store those informations in the memory and in a Database I wonder what's the best approach. I came up with the following solutions :

1. Each time a call from a client is made, update in memory values, establish a DB connection and store the new location.
2. Each time a call from a client is made, update in memory values, queue a task to update the values in the DB (using a ThreadPoolExecutor).
3. Each time a call from a client is made, only update in memory values. Then every 5 to 10 seconds a worker thread will store everything what's in memory.

**Option 1** is not really an option as it's very slow and resources consuming to do this.

**Option 2** looks ok to me but a bit more complicated and more resources consuming (in term of database connection) than **Option 3**

**Option 3** seems to be the best solutions to me as it only uses one DB connection and it's very fast to update the informations in memory. Also if the server crash, I would only lose 5 to 10 seconds of game state which is ok in my case.

Am I heading the right direction with **Option 3** or do you see a loophole there ?

Comment: Are you using connection pooling in step 1?  the overhead of creating a new connection every time is enormous when doing with this volume.  Connection pooling doesn't close the connection.  Instead it releases it back to a worker service that keeps track of what threads can be used by the application.

Comment: I don't plan to go for option 1 as explained above

Comment: Your question is (almost) meaningless without stating the specific goals of your design. For example, what is the point of storing information in the DB? To save the positions between server restarts? How often do the requests come? (The defining parameter for the system is not the number of users but the number of transactions per second.) What is your deployment plan (e.g. how many instances of the application will be running eventually), tolerance of the game to delays and data conflicts, etc. Without all that the questions can not be answered in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Franz I get that you don't want to use option one, but your reasoning for it as being "too slow" may be due to lack of connection pooling.  throwing out option one because it's "Slow and resource consuming" without understanding WHY it's that way means you may be omitting a valid option.  Alex Nevidomski has hit the nail on the head.  All review/analysis is moot without additional understanding of requirements.

Comment: Hum why don't you use plain JPA : it persist your object model (aka memory) into the db and if you use a correctly configured datasource then 10000 players shouldn't be a problem.